Bluetooth refuses to turn on
Bluetooth refuses to turn on. I used the following commands to address the issue.
sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center

I received the following system response.
$ sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 indicator-sound : Depends: pulseaudio
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please provide more info about the problem? It would be helpful to know your ubuntu version, for example.
